# line breaks in mysql the correct way?

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters, line-breaks

This may seem like a duplicate question but I've never found a consistent full solution. Answers on other posts seem to work for a short period of time then randomly break. I'm sure I'm making a rookie error.

What is the best 'complete' path to allow users to enter text into mysql and echo line breaks correctly. Handling all possibilities, e.g, 'return key', 'enter key', copy and paste from either word or from a website, and special character such as á, ', ".

**The current setup:**

MySQL row: type - text, colloation - utf8_unicode_ci

HTML: textarea

PHP submit:

```
$escaped = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST); 
$escaped = stripslashes($escaped);
```

PHP echo :

```
nl2br($textfield)
```

I'm unsure what the user does but on occasions it still echo `nn` or `n` instead of a break.

Thanks

*** Update **
I've been looking in completely the wrong place messing with these.
I've discovered Magic Quotes was enabled causing faults with line breaks and special characters.
Thank you for the help everyone.

Comment: How do you write the data to the database? Which functions?

Comment: Classic:  mysql_query("INSERT... however i know this is bad and in the process of updating all to PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this improve your situation:

```
$escaped = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST); 
$escaped = nl2br($textfield)
//$escaped = stripslashes($escaped);
```

edit:
Why strip slashes at all?

Whereby you search for and use the line breaks BEFORE stripping out the slashes. You an also explore using `PHP_EOL` special character but I *think* this is just the same as `\n` or `\r\n`

also for anyone else reading this, `mysql_` is ***deprecated*** and should be replaced with `MySQLi_`

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go for a while, I can't seem to recreate it myself as it only happens with some users.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove your `stripslashes($escaped)`.
It changes `\n` to `n` and `\n\n` to `nn`.

Comment: Without that I don't seem to be handling my ', ".. correctly?

Comment: People don't input `\n` directly.. And even if they, did it does not alter the '\n'..  [example](http://ideone.com/eliccM)

Comment: Did you try ? You shouldn't `stripslashes` the result of `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: @MF_it can you elaborate on "not handling correctly", if you do not use `stripslahes` then what is your *incorrect* output?